# Tail probability for the sum of laplace RIVs

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, random-variables

Suppose we have $n$ RIVs $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ where $\forall i. X_i \sim Lap(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$.
For convenience, we denote $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$.

Also, it is known that -
$$
Pr[Lap(\frac{1}{\epsilon}) \ge x]=\begin{cases}
1 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot exp(\epsilon \cdot x) &,x \le 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} \cdot exp(-\epsilon \cdot x) &, x>0
\end{cases}
$$

Knowing the last, how can bound the following tail probability -
$$
Pr[Y \ge z]
$$

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Knowing all the above, is there any way of reaching the following bound -
$$
Pr[|Y| \ge t] \leq 6 \cdot exp{(-\frac{\epsilon t}{\sqrt{2n}})}
$$

Answer (score 1):

we have
$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=0 \ \ \ \ \ \mathbb{V}[Y]=\sum^n\mathbb{V}[X_j]=\frac{2n}{\varepsilon^2}$$
Chebyschev inequality in this case states:
$$P\bigg(|Y|\geq c\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\varepsilon}\bigg)\leq \frac{1}{c^2}$$
For arbitrary $c >0$. The characteristic function of $Y$ is
$$\phi_Y(\omega)=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{\omega^2}{\varepsilon^2})^n}$$
It is entirely real, so the probability density of $Y$ is symmetric around the $y$ axis. Therefore
$$P\bigg(Y\geq c\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\varepsilon}\bigg)=\frac{1}{2}P\bigg(|Y|\geq c\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\varepsilon}\bigg)$$
so finally
$$P\bigg(Y\geq c\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\varepsilon}\bigg)\leq\frac{1}{2c^2}$$
for arbitrary $c>0$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any possibility of reaching -
$$
Pr[|Y| \ge t] \le 6 \cdot exp(- \frac{\epsilon \cdot t}{(2n)^\frac{1}{2}})
$$

Comment: Add this detail in the question

Comment: Added the details to the question. thanks!